# JBoss CLI UI commands do not work with cygwin mintty

Tags: jboss, windows-10, cygwin, command-line-interface

The CLI UI should permit such tasks as keyword expansion using the TAB-TAB sequence, up arrow recalls the previous command, and other such interface actions.  The TAB-TAB sequence works fine. The up arrow does nothing.  The Windows CMD shell works fine.  I've tried the various terminal types but no success.

Another problem is that the command start wrapping well before characters hit the right side of the screen.

The git bash shell has a start-up issue involving a file that exists.  (I'm chasing that one down now.)  For consistency, I want to stay with cygwin mintty.

Ideas?

Configuration:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.9.1" 2020-11-04 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.9.1+1-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.9.1+1-LTS, mixed mode)
```

I'm running JBoss EAP 7.3 on Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Have you tried `CYGWIN=disable_pcon` ? https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-cygwinenv.html

Comment: No.  I tried.  Still no response on up/down arrow.  I"ll review your reference.  Thanks.

Comment: I reviewed your reference.  It was interesting information which will be kept for future reference.  Since I use mintty, I would expect perhaps a mintty option.  Thanks.